# How to find partial derivative $\frac{u}{\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}} - \arctan\frac{u}{\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}} -1 = 0$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

How to find partial derivative in $(5;4)$ of implicit function $u(x;y)$ if we know this: $\frac{u}{\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}} - \arctan\frac{u}{\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}} -1 = 0$

I look on examples, and i will be do something like in them i will need firstly find $u(5;4)$

Here i get $\frac{u}{3} - \arctan\frac{u}{3} - 1 =0$, but here no rationals equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Set $z=\frac{u}{\sqrt {x^2-y^2}}$ and solve the transcendental equation for $z$ using your favourite root-finding approach.

Comment: The substitutions $x=5$ and $y=4$ should be the last step in your answer to the problem.